# How to store result of dynamically executed stored procedure into a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to assign result of a stored procedure executed dynamically into a variable. However when i call them, sql throw me this error:

> Could not find the stored procedure 'exec dbo.cont_com 3611,892;'

Below is the code snippet I am using:

```
declare @procedure_to_call varchar(max);
declare @procedure_result int;

set @procedure_to_call='exec dbo.cont_com 3611,892;'

exec @procedure_result=@procedure_to_call;
```

When I put parenthesis and execute the stored procedure, it works fine:

```
exec (@procedure_to_call);
```

But i need to save the return of the **@procedure_to_call** inside a variable.

This is the sample code for **dbo.cont_com** SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.cont_com
(   
    @id_c int,   
    @id_f int)
AS
BEGIN

    declare @porcent int;

    select @porcent=p.porcent 
    from porcent_table p
    where p.id_c=@id_c
    and p.id_c=@id_f;

    select porcent=@porcent;
    return @porcent;

END
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: EXECUTE sp_executesql @procedure_to_call will execute the dynamic sql, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
DECLARE @procedure_to_call NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'EXEC @x = dbo.cont_com 3611,892'
DECLARE @procedure_result INT;
SET @procedure_result = 0;

EXEC sp_executesql @procedure_to_call, N'@x INT OUT', @procedure_result OUT;
SELECT @procedure_result
```

It worked for me, hope it work for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
set @procedure_to_call='exec dbo.cont_com 3611,892;'

exec @procedure_result=@procedure_to_call;
```

This becomes

```
exec exec dbo.cont_com 3611,892; -- hence the error
```

`exec (@procedure_to_call)` gets around this by exectuing what's in the parentheses as its own activity

Try:

```
set @procedure_to_call='dbo.cont_com 3611,892;'
```

Comment: I try it, but now i have this error:

> Could not find the stored procedure 'dbo.cont_com 3611,892'.

this is the code now:

    set @procedure_to_call='dbo.cont_com 3611,892;'

    exec @procedure_result=@procedure_to_call;

I also try this:
    set @procedure_to_call='dbo.cont_com 3611,892;'

    exec @procedure_to_call;